# PHP json_encode results and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to take a jSON encoded string out of my database and loop through the items but I'm having some difficulty.  Here's the string in the database:

```
["volunteers","seat_dedication_program","memberships"]
```

And here is the code:

```
//Looks for _checkbox when looping through my database fields (object dbVals) and turns it into a true jQuery array if it finds it.
if( key.search(/_checkbox/i) > 0 ) var arr = $.makeArray(dbVals[key]);

//If it is an array, loop through the array values and show them
if($.isArray(arr)==true){
    $.each(arr, function(i, n){
        alert(i + " : " + n);
    });
}
```

What I want is this:

```
//alert
0 : volunteers
//alert
1 : seat_dedication_program etc...
```

What I'm getting is this:

```
//alert
0 : ["volunteers","seat_dedication_program","memberships"]
```

I think I've included all relevant data.  Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $.makeArray(..) is giving you an array where the only element is the string you gave it.  You need to parse the string into a JavaScript object.  Use the [JSON2.js library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to parse then your code would look something like this.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(dbVals[key]);

if($.isArray(arr)==true){
    $.each(arr, function(i, n){
        alert(i + " : " + n);
    });
}
```

Comment: @Carl, that's what I thought (only element is the string I gave it) but when I use json_encode in php, why should I then have to parse it?

Comment: json_encode return a string, to have it treated as JSON in javascript it needs to be not a string.

Comment: Like @Greg said, json_encode gives you a string (object -> string). In PHP, you'd use json_decode to get back to an object.  Since you're in JS, JSON.parse(..) is the analog to json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular for loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var n = arr[i];
    alert(i + " : " + n);
}
```

or for large arrays, the slightly optimized:

```
for (var i=0,l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
    var n = arr[i];
    alert(i + " : " + n);
}
```

or if you really hate for loops:

```
Array.prototype.each = function (callback) {
    for (var index=0,l=this.length;index<l;index++) {
        var item = this[index];

        // index is second arg since it's optional
        callback(item,index);
    }
}

arr.each(function(n,i){
    alert(i + " : " + n);
});
```

but I'd recommend the for loop to avoid clashing with library modifications or when Firefox suddenly decide to implement its own `each` method for arrays (some libraries have already been bitten by this).

Comment: It cannot throw arr not defined because the OP uses `arr` as the array variable and has already checked `$.isArray(arr)==true`